# How do I turn a group presentation into a multiplication table?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose I have a group presentation and I know for a fact that this is a presentation of some finite group. How do I create a multiplication table from this presentation?

Comment: There is no general algorithm. Such an algorithm would solve the group isomorphism problem which is undecidable.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip are there any tactics?

Comment: The best general method for this is probably Todd Coxeter coset enumeration over the trivial subgroup. But normally you only want to explicitly compute the complete multiplication table for very small groups.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip But the quewstion clearly says that we know that the group is finite. Assuming that information, you can compute its multiplication table, although you cannot predict in advance how long it might take, even if you are given an upper bound on the group order.

Comment: A classic question asked by Conway was: Is the group $\langle x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\mid x_ix_{i+1}=x_{i+2}\rangle$ (subscripts calculated mod $5$) finite?" I forget the exact history, but basically it was a tough question and took a couple of years for people to post the answer. It turns out that the group is cyclic, of order $11$. There is a book of DL Johnson *Presentations of groups*, which gives the history of Conways question. The book suggests using coset enumeration on a computer to solve the question (as Derek Holt is suggesting).

Comment: @DerekHolt, okay, I believe you, but it's not clear to me how you list distinct elements in the group.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Once coset enumeration over the trivial subgroup has completed, the cosets in the table correspond to the group elements, and it is straightforward to calculate a word representing each element. But I really don't want to start describing coset enumeration here!